# Eclipse C: Some projects cannot be imported because their project description file is corrupted

Tags: c, eclipse, import

I moved my workspace folder from drive C to drive D. I deleted the old folder in drive C and recycle bin because I thought all the files were moved but they weren't so I had to recover 21/40 projects (They're for my programming class; bunch of coding practice).

Luckily, I managed to recover them so I tried to import them in Eclipse (They're already in a new workspace in drive D) but I keep getting the error **'Some projects cannot be imported because their project description file is corrupted'**.

What could be the problem? And how can I import them? Most of the projects have .project, .cproject, .settings files. Is there a way I can get the source codes if I can't import them?

PS. Sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language.

Comment: The source is still available as physical files. I'd recommend to create a new project from scratch, preferably in a sound IDE which doesn't come with some useless "workspace" bloat for the sole purpose of causing problems.

Comment: It sounds like some of the .project or .cproject files were not recovered correctly. These are plain text XML files - do they look OK if you just look at their contents?

Comment: I tried opening a .project file in a browser, it showed a bunch of random characters and words but not the source code. Same thing happened with the .cproject... @greg-449

Comment: Then the files were not recovered correctly. You could try creating a new project and add the C source files to that - but the C source might also not have been recovered properly.